# Knitr and/or Kableextra: Global Table Options?

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to instruct Rmarkdown to default all tables to my styled output?  Here is my attempt:

````
---
title: 'Test Kable Global Styling'
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: kable
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable <- function(data) {
   message("YES, IT BITES!  (not sortable, but styled.)\n")
   knitr::kable(data, digits=3) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "center")
}

```


## Testing

```{r}
d <- data.frame( x=1:3, y=rnorm(3) )
```

### Explicit Invokation

```{r}
kable(d)
```

### Implicit Invokation Fails

```{r}
d
```
````

The output looks like this:

[image: sample failed output]

[possibly related to [How to set knitr::kable() global options in markdown for reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168558/how-to-set-knitrkable-global-options-in-markdown-for-reuse]), but defining my own kable function is not enough for Rmarkdown to select it.

---

thanks, mystery user for the complete solved update to the above problem.  alas, could it generalize to :

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
library(DT); p <- function(...) DT::datatable(...)
knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) asis_output(  paste( c("",p(x)) , collapse="\n" )  )
registerS3method("knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame)
```

# Test Code

```{r}
d <- data.frame( x=1:3, y=rnorm(3) )
```

## Print

```{r}
p(d)

d
```

done
````

Answer (score 2):

As you saw, [How to set knitr::kable() global options in markdown for reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168558/how-to-set-knitrkable-global-options-in-markdown-for-reuse) describes how to do this with an explicit call to `kable`, but doesn't handle implicit displays.  The way to do that is described in the `?knitr::knit_print` help page.  You need code like this early in your document:

```
kable <- function(data, ...) {
   message("YES, IT BITES!  (not sortable, but styled.)\n")
   knitr::kable(data, digits=3, ...) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "center")
}
knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  res <- paste(c("", "", kable(x)), collapse = "\n")
  asis_output(res)
}
registerS3method("knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame)
```

Comment: it works great, but it does not generalize!?  `library(knitr);
library(DT); p <- function(...) DT::datatable(...);
knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) asis_output(  paste( c("",p(x)) , collapse="\n" )  );
registerS3method("knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame);
` has `p(d)` work, but not `d`.  can this be generalized?

Comment: If `d` is a dataframe, it will work.  If it is something else, you'll need to set the S3 method on that class as well.